# PHPlot only showing 2 of 3 results with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts, pie-chart

I've got a pie chart, and I want it to show 3 results. I'm using code from a 2 line chart and that works fine, I just want it to show all 3 results. The legend shows all 3, but the chart only shows the first two. I know there's an error in my code, I just can't find it. Any suggestions?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT totaldep, totalmania, totalanxiety FROM $dbmood ORDER BY DATE ASC";

//Define the object


$rslt1 = @mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die("Couldn't execute select:".@mysql_error());   

// I'm assuming it's somewhere in here, I just can't see it
 $iid = "-1";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rslt1)) {

                if ($row[0] != $iid)     {
                        $iid = $row[0];
                } else {
                    $row[0] = '';
            }
// between there and here

            $graph_data[] = $row;           

//Define some data
$example_data = $graph_data;

        }




//Define the object
$graph =& new PHPlot(300,250);
$graph->SetPlotType("pie");
$legend = array();
$legend[] = "Depression";
$legend[] = "Mania";
// It isn't showing anxiety, everything else is showing/updating fine
$legend[] = "Anxiety";


$graph->SetDataValues($example_data);
$graph->SetLegendPixels(1,5,false);
$graph->SetLegend($legend);

//Draw it
$graph->DrawGraph();
```

Thanks in advance, you guys always help!

Comment: Don't use these functions (mysql_). They're deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by pulling them out individually

```
$datab = mysql_select_db( 'medtrack', $conn ) or die(mysql_error());

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $dbmood ORDER BY DATE ASC";



$getit = mysql_query ( $sql1, $conn );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getit, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$dep="{$row['totaldep']}";
$man="{$row['totalmania']}";
$anx="{$row['totalanxiety']}";


$example_data = array(
array('a',$dep,$man,$anx)
);
}


//Include the code

//Define the object
$graph =& new PHPlot(300,250);
$graph->SetPlotType("pie");
$legend = array();
$legend[] = "Depression";
$legend[] = "Mania";
$legend[] = "Anxiety";


$graph->SetDataValues($example_data);
$graph->SetLegendPixels(1,5,false);
$graph->SetLegend($legend);
//Draw it
$graph->DrawGraph();
```